# Change objects that meet certain criteria in list

Tags: jquery

I would like to change the css (color in particular) of a list item when it is above a particular position on the screen.  I can make the entire list change when the first list-item is above the position, but i cannot seem to figure out how to change only the items that are above the mark.

Example, first see Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wzfu322h/

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    $('#list').append('<li id="li' + i + '">' + i + '</li>');
}
var containerBottom = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect().bottom - 25;

var listElement = $('li');
var checkScroll = function () {
    if ($('#container').find(listElement).position().top < containerBottom) {
        $('#container').find(listElement).css("color", "#FFF");
    }
};
$('#container').scroll(checkScroll);
```

I'm trying to use `find()` , among other methods ie: `sibling()` or `children()`, however not sure if this is the correct approach.  I am aware that I am changing the css of all list items by changing the `$('#container')` object.  The direct question is, how can i change each list item as they pass a particular physical position on the list? (in this case 25px above the bottom of its container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your function on each list item individually:

```
var listElement = $('#container li');

var checkScroll = function () {
    $(listElement).each(function () {
        if ($(this).position().top < containerBottom) {
            $(this).css("color", "#FFF");
        }
    });
};
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/wzfu322h/6)

Comment: Thank you very much.  Don't know the basic functions yet.  Had difficulty researching what I wanted to do without explaining the whole thing.